# What PHP framework would you choose for a new Facebook application and why?

Tags: php, facebook, frameworks

Considering facebook application is to be developed in PHP, which PHP framework (code igniter, Yii, cake php etc.) would you use?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a framework for that. Considering that facebook has a really nice API and an SDK for development - I would write my own framework.

But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

None. I'd core-code it.
I'm not a fan of frame-works, instead of actually simplifying things, they complicate things.

Comment: Lol. Even after half a year negative votes are still coming in.

Answer (score 0):

well it also depends on the what scale you are building your FB app

for small app i would not consider any framework

but if the app is big then i will prefer codeigniter or Zend framework